# Ruby 'OR' for string literals

Tags: ruby, string, compare

How would i re-factor something like this?

```
response = "yes"

if response == "yes" or response == "y"
  puts "Do Something"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if %w(yes y).include?(response)
```

Comment: Wonder if 'or' is more readable if there is an 'elsif' clause.

Comment: You can also use: `case response; when 'yes', 'y'; ...; when 'no', 'n'; ...; else; ...; end`, should be even better if it's readability you're after :D

Comment: Oh i didn't realize i could use case a,b. This is so much better :D

Answer (score -1):

humm you can use like as follow , i hope it will help you

**Sample**

if @response == 'R'  || @response == 'r'

If you put **OR** then it will show you an error

Comment: Ruby has both `&&`/`||` as well as `and`/`or`. The only difference is in priority.